# canvas is empty in firefox 36

Tags: javascript, firefox, canvas, three.js

Application consists of interface (html) and workspace (canvas).
We use three.js for generation elements on canvas.
On chrome, opera and firefox 35 it's working fine.
http://clip2net.com/s/3e7OwfF

But in firefox 36.0.1 canvas is empty (see http://clip2net.com/s/3e7QkdH ). All event on 3d elements is working. I see that render is completed.

If I open context menu on canvas and select 'Save Image As...' then correct image saving (with all rendered elements).

When I resize browser's window then canvas is showing.

Can you help?

Comment: We need to see some setup code. Sounds initially as a async/loading problem but there could be many reasons..

Comment: I not think that setup code will helpful. Application URL - https://cube.spatialnote.com/
Code is minify and have very many classes...
I think that it is not issue of async/loading. Because on firefox 35.0 (or lower) and other browsers all is working. And when I select Save Image As... on canvas then image save with all elements. May be canvas re-render if click Save Image As...

Comment: Hi, I´m using three.js (r68) and I have the same problem. Tested also r71 with same problem. I can´t get rid of the problem, No workaround I try is working.

Comment: Mr. Doob should have a look on this. I think three.js is causing the wierd behaviour

Comment: The Problem seems to be the WebGLRenderer. When using CanvasRenderer all is working fine. But Canvasrenderer sometimes suck, and the performance is ugly on firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I´ve found the problem in my app.

I´ve used WebGLRenderer this way:

```
 renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true, preserveDrawingBuffer: true } );
```

When I use It this way, the canvas isn´t cleared:(But then you can´t do your Screenshots I think):

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I deleted 'preserveDrawingBuffer: true' and now canvas is working in firefox 36.0.1. Thank you.